# Failed to build Web API NET 7 in VS 2022 17.9.1

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem running the VS 2022 application
.net 7.0 has the following crash.

`Error MSB3030 Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\net7.0\xxxxxx.CrossCutting.Util.dll" because it was not found.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIrbU.png)

I've already made several attempts to resolve it.
Clear Cache
Clear Nugget Cache
Clear Temp
Reinstall VS

Another application I have on net core 3.1 also presents the same error in VS2022

However, in VS2019 the net core 3.1 application builds normally without errors.

Installed SDKs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mtWI.png)

I have already tested with the VS2022 Preview Version 17.10.0 Preview 1.0 and it shows the same errors

I've already made several attempts to resolve it.
Clear Cache
Clear Nugget Cache
Clear Temp
Reinstall VS

I have already tested with the VS2022 Preview Version 17.10.0 Preview 1.0 and it shows the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, after several attempts I realized that when activating this option in VS2022 the build error started to appear.

Even formatting the PC and reinstalling VS2022 shows this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cueKF.png)